# How can I calculate Feigenbaum's constant?

Tags: dynamical-systems, self-learning, chaos-theory, python, bifurcation

So I am trying to calculate Feigenbaum's constant for the logistic map: $$ x_{n+1} = 4 \lambda x_n (1-x_n) $$
I am writing this through python and the main pieces I have for my code that are relevant are:

```
def logistic(L,x):
    return 4*L*x*(1-x)
n = 1000
iterations = 1000
keep = 500
L = np.linspace(0.4,1.0,n)
x = 1e-4 * np.ones(n)
for i in range(iterations):
    x = logistic(L,x)

    if i >= (iterations - keep):
        plt.plot(L,x,'.k', markersize=0.1)
```

**I currently only have the packages numpy and matplotlib imported in my code.**

So this gives me a nice bifurcation diagram but I was curious about how I would be able to calculate Feigenbaum's constant from this? I know I can go through it region by region and manually calculate the sections where I get period doubling but I would like to be able to do something more robust. I did read on Wikipedia that Feigenbaum's constant can be calculated from: $$ \frac{\lambda_{n-1} - \lambda_{n-2}}{\lambda_{n-1} - \lambda_{n}} $$ for the sections of period doubling. But again from the current code I have in place, I can only think of doing this through manual calculation. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure whether there is a shortcut. I think, Wikipedia only mentions the Feigenbaum constants, I did not see a method to find them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky. Here's my try:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from random import random

seed = 0.6765432
n = 1000                         # number of different rate values
iters = 1000                     # number of logistic map 
iterations
acc = 8                         # number accuracy


def logistic(L, x):
    return L*x*(1-x)

def check(x):
    if x[1] == x[0]: return True
    else: return False

def feigenbaum(seed, acc, iters, n):
    '''computes Feigenbaum constant with acc accuracy,
    beggining from seed,
    iterate iters times the logistic function in different 
columns,
    for n different values of R'''
    
    data = pd.DataFrame({'L': np.linspace(0.4, 4.0, n), 1: seed * 
np.ones(n)})
    # create the R series and the seed column

    for i in range(2, iters):
        data[i] = logistic(data['L'], data[i - 1])  # create the 
iterations in new columns
    
    drop_cols = list(range(1, iters - 50))
    data = data.drop(columns= drop_cols)            # keep the last 50 iterations
    data = data.round(acc)                          # round to acc
    
    points = data.melt(id_vars= 'L').groupby('L').nunique()     
    # iterations in one column, then group by R, counting the unique values for each R
    points['Fluctuation'] = points.value.rolling(2).apply(check)
    # check for fluctuations (random occurences of values) by checking rows different from successors (one row error!)
    points = points[points.Fluctuation == True]    # drop fluctuations
    
    doubling = points[(points.value == 2) | (points.value == 4) | (points.value == 8)]
    # select powers of 2 occurences
    doubling = doubling.drop(columns= ['L', 'variable']).reset_index()
    doubling = doubling.groupby('value').min()
    # getting R value for every doubling
    
    feigenbaum = (doubling.loc[4] - doubling.loc[2]) / (doubling.loc[8] - doubling.loc[4])
    
    return round(feigenbaum[0], acc)
   

print(feigenbaum(random(), acc, iters, n))
```

I created this answer since I didn't find anything relevant online. I would appreciate any comments or further contribution!

Comment: Please use three backticks to surround your code, this way it is more readable.